# Runtime Exception Incorrect Syntax Near '='

Tags: asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="postreplyadmin.aspx.cs" Inherits="postreplay" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.master" Title="Post-Reply Page"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<%
    String postid = Request.QueryString["id"];
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["civilRegDB"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID=" + postid;
    SqlDataAdapter da=new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);        
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataRow drow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
    String name = drow["Name"].ToString();
    String desc = drow["Description"].ToString();
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(drow["PostDate"].ToString());
    String postdate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
    String mailid = drow["Email"].ToString();
    %>
</asp:content>
```

I'm getting a sqlexception while i'm trying to Reply to post. The error: Incorrect syntax near '='. I've looked around to find other questions similar to mine, but I can't find anything worth to me.

I'm getting Error on "da.fill(ds);". Anyone can help me out on this...:(

Answer (score 2):

Your `postid` is a string it should be enclosed with single quotes `'`

```
String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID='" + postid +"'";
```

But better if you use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) to save yourself from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Like:

```
String postid = Request.QueryString["id"];
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["civilRegDB"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID=@postID"; //parameter
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("postID", postid);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); // pass command to adapter
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataRow drow = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
String name = drow["Name"].ToString();
String desc = drow["Description"].ToString();
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(drow["PostDate"].ToString());
String postdate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
String mailid = drow["Email"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

`postid` from the query string probably does not have a value, and as a result the TSQL statement is invalid.

Add a check for whether the query string value is provided.

Also verify that it's value is in the range you expect and consider using prepared statements/parameters - Your current method is leaving you open to sql injection.

Comment: What is the value for postid?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried following as suggested in one of the answers

Replace `String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID=" + postid;`

with `String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID='" + postid + "'";`

**OR:**

If it does not work, then may be you will have to use int directly in query.
For this, just get your queryString value in integer variable.
Like:

```
int postid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

and

```
String sql = "select * from Forumthread where PostID=" + postid;
```